# Javascript regular expression validate phone number

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to validate phone number by regular expression. The phone number should

- Start with (9|09|8869|+8869)
- Followed by 8 digit [0-9]

I come up with `/(09|9|8869|+8869)[0-9]{8}$/g`.
I test with +8869900000000 and expect it will not match but actually it passed
Could you help me to address the regex problem? And how do I fix it?

Comment: `|+` is an invalid pattern - you can't repeat an alternation like that.

Comment: `/(09|9|8869)[0-9]{8}$/g` Is this correct? I allow the user to enter `+`

Comment: You should escape the `+` like `\+` and you might add an anchor to assert the start of the string `^(?:09|9|8869|\+8869)[0-9]{8}$` If you don't need the capturing group you could turn that into a noncapturing one using `(?:` [demo](https://regex101.com/r/hAvrHs/1)

Comment: ^(09|9|8869|\+8869)[0-9]{8}$

Answer (score 1):

You can use this regex: `/^(0?9|\+?8869)\d{8}$/`

The group (0?9|+?8869) is for your starting condition where 0 is optional before 9 and + is optional before 8869.

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/1OpYl0/1/

Answer (score 0):

The regex you are looking for is : `^(([0]?9)|([+]?8869))[0-9]{8}$`

Note the way round brackets used to determine the conditions. We need to match within any of the 2 subsets and then precede it 8 digits.

Comment: You can omit 2 sets of parenthesis and the 0 does not have to be between square brackets `^(0?9|[+]?8869)[0-9]{8}$`